# How to automatically host ASP.NET MVC application in IIS when users subscribe it from website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, deployment

I have a web application that needs to be hosted for every customer manually in IIS when they request/subscribe to it from the website, today.

I would like to know how can this hosting process be automated, just like a SAAS, so that, when a user subscribes to it, a new application is hosted in IIS, and sends them a link via email to access their app.

No plan to move to any cloud platform until having enough customers-

Comment: That heavily depends on what kind of experience you want to deliver. A PowerShell script might be a good start, while ultimately you can use `Microsoft.Web.Administration` if you want more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Lex Li said, you can use scripts and automation tools to create new IIS websites and configure them for each customer. PowerShell is a powerful tool for this task. The following is a simplified example:

```
# Define variables
$webName = "webName"
$webAppPath = "C:\Path\To\Your\WebApp"

# Create a new IIS website
New-IISSite -Name $webName -BindingInformation "*:8080:" -PhysicalPath $webAppPath

# Start the website
Start-IISSite -Name $webName
```

This script creates a new IIS website. You should customize this script to meet your specific requirements, such as setting up an application pool, configuring SSL, etc.

Related link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration/new-iissite?view=windowsserver2022-ps